# BFS algorithm for maze not looping - Javascript

Tags: javascript, breadth-first-search, maze

I am trying to use a BFS algorithm to solve a maze, which I have represented in an array where all the elements start as 999 except the centre (goal) which is 0.  I am trying to have the code start from 0 and branch out four ways (north/south/east/west) and if the number is greater than the parent, add 1 to the parent number.  The initial loop should have a 0 in the middle and the four adjacent cell should update to 1 from 999.  This should loop over until the algorithm reaches position 0,0.  Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to get the loop running - I can get the first four elements updated to 1 and then it just stops.  I think it is to do with how my queue is / isn't being picked up as the next loop's (y,x) input but I can't seem to get this to change.
This is an assignment so not looking for a solution but any assistance in helping me see what I am missing for the loop would be greatly appreciated.  I have shown the array code (mazeD) and the BFS/flood code below

```
// maze array showing numerical distance
let mazeD = [];
for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  let row = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    row[x] = 999;
  }
  mazeD[y] = row;
}

mazeD[5][5] = 0;

// BFS function
function flood(x, y, d) {
  let queue = []
  queue.push([y, x]);
  while (queue.length > 0) {
    queue.shift();
    let fillArr = [
      [+y - 1, +x],
      [+y, +x - 1],
      [+y, +x + 1],
      [+y + 1, +x],
    ];
    if ((x < 10) && (y < 10)) {
      d++;
      for (let [yy, xx] of fillArr) {
      if (mazeD[yy][xx] > d) {
        queue.push([yy, xx]);
        mazeD[yy][xx] = d;
        console.log("queue =" +queue)
      }
    } 
  }
 }
}
flood(5, 5, 0);
console.log(mazeD);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
let mazeD = [];
for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  let row = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    row[x] = 999;
  }
  mazeD[y] = row;
}

mazeD[5][5] = 0;

// BFS function
function flood(x, y, d) {
  let queue = [];
  let i = 0;
  queue.push([y, x]);

  while (i < queue.length) {
    
    [x,y] = queue[i,i];
    let fillArr = [
      [+y - 1, +x],
      [+y, +x - 1],
      [+y, +x + 1],
      [+y + 1, +x],
    ];
    if ((x < 10) && (y < 10) && x >=0 && y>=0) 
    {
      for (let [yy, xx] of fillArr) 
      {
        
      if(yy >=0 && yy < 10 && xx>=0 && xx<10)
      {
          if (mazeD[yy][xx] == 999) 
          {
            queue.push([yy, xx]);
            mazeD[yy][xx] = mazeD[y][x]+1;
            console.log(xx,yy,mazeD[y][x]+1);
          }
          if(xx == 0 && yy == 0){
            return;
          }
      }
      
    } 
  
   }
   i++;
  }
}
flood(5, 5, 0);
console.log(mazeD);
```

Comment: Thanks Nao! I am still working on properly troubleshooting so this gives me a great comparison to work through, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an issue in this line:

```
queue.shift()
```

It seems you're never reading the values that were stored in the queue, so the coordinates in your loop are never updated, which means you're always checking the same positions. You probably want to assign the value of `queue.shift()` to a variable and use those coordinates to continue the search.

Comment: thank you :) I can see I am not referencing the queue so will try adding a line near the end of the while loop.  I thought queue.shift() removed the 0th term in my queue array which should then move the co-ordinates of my next loop to the 0th position.  Is this the incorrect method?

Comment: You're correct in that `queue.shift()` removes the 0th position of the queue and allows you to visit the next item in the queue. What you're not doing, however, is checking the neighbouring nodes of that particular node you just removed -- and adding them to the queue. That means once you visit all the neighbouring nodes of your starting point, your queue will be empty and the loop will stop.

Comment: Have a look at this implementation https://gist.github.com/keif/96c49cae3bd62dc9651cc66f8561672e for reference; particularly lines 41 onward

Comment: Thanks again Danilo - this ref is super helpful :)